# How to Clone an custom entity in dynamics 365 using javaScript

Tags: javascript, clone, dynamics-365

I came across an scenario where I have to clone my custom entity.
Then I have started doing using with JavaScript by placing a custom duplicate button in the ribbon which triggers my JavaScript.

I used the following code:

```
function duplicateOrder(primaryControl){
var formContext = primaryControl;
var city = formContext.getAttribute('new_city').getValue();
var country = formContext.getAttribute('new_country').getValue();
var state = formContext.getAttribute('new_state').getValue();
var postal_code = formContext.getAttribute('new_zipcodepostalcode').getValue();

// var formItem = formContext.ui.formSelector.items.get();
// alert(`the form item value is ${formItem}`);
formContext.data.entity.save('saveandnew');

sleep(3000);
var city1 = formContext.getAttribute('new_city').getValue();
var country1 = formContext.getAttribute('new_country').getValue();
var state1 = formContext.getAttribute('new_state').getValue();
var postal_code1 = formContext.getAttribute('new_zipcodepostalcode').getValue();

alert(`${city1},${country1},${state1},${postal_code1}`);

if(city1==null){
    formContext.getAttribute('new_city').setValue(city);
}
if(country1==null){
    formContext.getAttribute('new_country').setValue(country);
}
if(state1==null){
    formContext.getAttribute('new_state').setValue(state);
}
if(postal_code1==null){
    formContext.getAttribute('new_zipcodepostalcode').setValue(postal_code);
}
alert(`${city},${country},${state},${postal_code}`);
}

function sleep(milliseconds) {
const date = Date.now();
let currentDate = null;
do {
  currentDate = Date.now();
} while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
}
```

I tried using the save and new logic to open a new entity form.
The New entity form opens but the field values do not get copied in the new how.

Please help me how to solve this.
Thanks and advance!

Comment: Did you try cloneNode?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call Xrm.Navigation.openForm with your cloneid record.

```
// Load newly copy record
     var entityFormOptions = {};
     entityFormOptions["entityName"] = "stdseries";
     entityFormOptions["entityId"] = cloneId;
     // Open the form.
     Xrm.Navigation.openForm(entityFormOptions).then(
         function (success) {
             formContext.data.refresh();        
         },
         function (error) {
             
         });
```